# Cannot reference a local function with captures from another local function

Tags: swift, xcode6.1

```
func setupInvaders() {
        // 1
        let baseOrigin = CGPoint(x:size.width / 3, y:180)
        for var row = 1; row <= kInvaderRowCount; row++ {
            // 2
            var invaderType: InvaderType
            if row % 3 == 0 {
                invaderType = .A
            } else if row % 3 == 1 {
                invaderType = .B
            } else {
                invaderType = .C
            }
            // 3
            let invaderPositionY = CGFloat(row) * (kInvaderSize.height * 2) + baseOrigin.y
            var invaderPosition = CGPoint(x:baseOrigin.x, y:invaderPositionY)
            // 4
            for var col = 1; col <= kInvaderColCount; col++ {
                // 5
                var invader = makeInvaderOfType(invaderType) //ERROR HERE
                invader.position = invaderPosition
                addChild(invader)
                // 6
                invaderPosition = CGPoint(x: invaderPosition.x + kInvaderSize.width + kInvaderGridSpacing.width, y: invaderPositionY)
            }
        }
    }
```

Can't seem to get past this error.  I used a closure but maybe I'm typing it wrong?  I'm really not sure at what causes this problem, if you have a clue, please help.

Comment: What makeInvaderOfType does? What is the error? Compile error or runtime.

Comment: Here is the code:  **func createContent() {
    
    func makeInvaderOfType(invaderType: InvaderType) -> (SKNode) {**            .............  It creates 3 rows of sprites that are supposed to collide with a bullet and disappear ..... the error is _Cannot reference a local function with captures from another local function_